# Different behavior of `public_send` in Ruby 2.6 / 2.7

Tags: ruby, keyword-argument, ruby-2.6, ruby-2.7

```rb
class A
  def a
    1
  end
end

a = A.new
x = {}

a.a(**x) # => 1 in both Ruby 2.6 and 2.7

a.public_send(:a, **x) # => 1 in Ruby 2.7
```

In Ruby 2.6, however:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Is this a bug in pre-2.7 `public_send`/`send`/`__send__`?
What would you suggest to overcome this difference?

You can check this failing live [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38386/files#diff-dee764b95770b23869cd6ce3351109f5R190).

Comment: It turns out that `new` is suffering from the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby 2.6 and before, the `**argument` syntax was mostly (but not entirely) syntactic sugar for a passed hash. This was done to keep the convention to pass a variable hash as the last argument to a method valid.

With Ruby 2.7, keyword arguments however were semantically updated and do not map to a hash parameter anymore. Here, the keyword arguments are handled from the positional arguments.

In Ruby 2.6 and before, the following two method definitions where (for many aspects at least) equivalent:

```
def one(args={})
  #...
end

def two(**args)
  #...
end
```

In both cases, you could pass either a verbatim hash or a splatted hash with the same result:

```
arguments = {foo: :bar}

one(arguments)
one(**arguments)

two(arguments)
two(**arguments)
```

With Ruby 2.7 however, you should pass the keyword arguments as such (the previous behavior still works but is deprecated with a warning). Thus, the call to `two(arguments)` will result in a deprecation warning in 2.7 and will become invalid in Ruby 3.0.

Internally, a splatted hash argument (which passes keyword arguments to a method) thus results in an empty keyword argument list in Ruby 2.7, but a positional argument with an empty Hash in 2.6.

You can see what happens here in detail by verifying how Ruby interprets  arguments to its `public_send` method. In Ruby 2.6 and earlier, the method has effectively the following interface:

```
def public_send26(method_name, *args, &block);
  p method_name
  p args

  # we then effectively call
  #    self.method_name(*args, &block)
  # internally from C code

  nil
end
```

When calling this method in Ruby 2.6 as `public_send26(:a, **{}`), you will see that the keyword arguments are again "wrapped" in a Hash:

```
:a
[{}]
```

With Ruby 2.7, you have the following effective interface instead:

```
def public_send27(method_name, *args, **kwargs, &block);
  p method_name
  p args
  p **kwargs

  # Here, we then effectively call
  #    self.method_name(*args, **kwargs, &block)
  # internally from C code

  nil
end
```

You can see that the keyword arguments are separately handled and retained as keyword arguments in Ruby 2.7, rather than they being handled as a regular positional Hash argument to the method as was done in Ruby 2.6 and earlier.

Ruby 2.7 still contains fallback behavior so that code  expecting the Ruby 2.6 behavior still works (although with a warning). In Ruby 3.0, you HAVE to  strictly separate keyword arguments and positional arguments. You can find some additional description of these changes in [a news entry on  ruby-lang.org](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/).

Comment: I see your point, but there are a couple of things that confuse me.

1. A call with varargs `one(*args)` is equivalent to `one()` if `args` were `[]`, but the same applied to kwargs is not the case.

2. As you may see, a regular call (`a.a(**x)`) works as expected, while `public_send`'s behavior is different.

I have no complaints regarding separation of positional and kwargs or 2.7's behavior in general, it's pre-2.7's `public_send`/`send`'s behavior that I perceive as questionable.

Comment: The same issue applies here. In Ruby 2.6 (and before), the splashed Hash argument (denoting your keyword arguments) is transformed to an actual Hash in the call to `public_send` and then send as an actual Hash object to your `a` method since the method doesn't define keyword arguments (and keyword arguments are merely syntactic sugar here as explained in my answer). In Ruby 2.7 and later, the passed arguments are instead retained as separate keyword arguments since you pass them with a double-splash.